# How to find records in single projection query in mongodb based on regex expression in aggregation?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

I have a collection that name is **web_events**

and data is saved in something below structure.

```
{
    "subscriber_id" : "amit",
    "event" : "login"
},
{
    "subscriber_id" : "manish",
    "event" : "login"        
},
{
     "subscriber_id" : "manish",
    "event" : "page_view"        
},
{
    "subscriber_id" : "manish",
    "event" : "add_to_cart"       
}
```

and i want to find out how many user do (login) event
and how many user do (login,add_to_cart) both events

output would be like ....
** (login) event count -  2, users and (login,add_to_cart) event count-- 1 user
in one query**

I am using two query for this....
**for login below query**

```
db.web_events.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{subscriber_id:"$subscriber_id"},myfield:{$push:{$concat:["$event"]}}}},{$project:{"results":{$reduce:{input:"$myfield",initialValue:'',in:{$concat:["$$value","$$this"]}}}}},{$match:{results:{$regex:/.*login.*/}}}]);
```

and **login and add_tocart**

```
db.web_events.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{subscriber_id:"$subscriber_id"},myfield:{$push:{$concat:["$event"]}}}},{$project:{"results":{$reduce:{input:"$myfield",initialValue:'',in:{$concat:["$$value","$$this"]}}}}},{$match:{results:{$regex:/.*login.*add_to_cart.*/}}}]);
```

I want to run both the aggregations in single projection query.

Any help is appreciated.